# How can I load ember model after successful ajax call in Emberjs?

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js

I have defined a model called `todo.js` in `app/models` like this:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  created_at: DS.attr('date'),
  updated_at: DS.attr('date'),
  is_deleted: DS.attr('boolean'),
  is_done: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

Let's say I don't want to use to `ember-data` & I simply want to use plain old `ajax` like this:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return Ember.$.getJSON('http://localhost:3001/todo').then((data) => {
       // How would I load the data into the model here?
    });
  }
});
```

How would I load the data I am getting from the successful `ajax` call into the model?

I have defined a component to show todos like this:

```
<ul>
  {{#each model as |todo index|}}
    {{#link-to 'todo' todo.id}}<li>{{todo.title}}</li>{{/link-to}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

And here's the `router.js`:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('todos');
  this.route('todo', { path: '/todo/:todo_id' })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pushPayload method](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.14.10/classes/DS.Store/methods/pushPayload?anchor=pushPayload&show=inherited,protected,private,deprecated) and [peekAll](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.14/classes/DS.Store/methods/peekAll?anchor=peekAll) .

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return Ember.$.getJSON('http://localhost:3001/todo').then((data) => {
       this.get('store').pushPayload('todo',data);
       return this.get('store').peekAll('todo');
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: It may be a stupid question, why can't I just return `this.get('store').pushPayload('todo',data);` ?

Comment: pushPayload is not returning any value. but it will load all the data into the store. so you need to peekAll the record.

Comment: I see, thanks @kumkanillam! I tried using `pushPayload` & I could see the model filling up but the template was not rendering. That explains it.

Comment: Remember peekAll is live record array which means whenever you update store with new record it will be updated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use ember-data just don't use it:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return Ember.RSVP.resolve(Ember.$.getJSON('http://localhost:3001/todo'));
  }
});
```

this will work as expected and give you access to the returning JSON under `model`. So for your template just make sure `http://localhost:3001/todo` sends a JSON like this:

```
[{
    "id": "a",
    "title": "foo"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return Ember.$.getJSON('http://localhost:3001/todo').then((data) => {
           return Ember.Object.create(data);
        });
    }
});
```